# Database query taking a lot of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, firebird

I have an asp.net(mvc) project which more or less resembles a webshop (Entity Framework is used in a project to create db entities). I am using a webservice to get all the information about each detail in list, and then I have to request prices for each detail from Firebird database.

```
foreach (var item in DetailList)
{                
      try
      {
           item.price = db.PRECES.Where(e => e.RAZOTAJA_KODI == item.articleNo ).Select(e => e.REALIZ_CENA).First();
      }
      catch
      { 
           item.price = 0;
      }
}
```

This simple request takes a lot of time. Here are the statistics:

> Program total time: 5.589 (seconds)
>
> Webservice total response time: 2.627 (seconds)
>
> Database prices total response time: 2.954 (seconds)

So the webservice response is taking less time, but there all the info about each detail is set, including photos, files and so on. A simple request to the Firebird database is taking as much, and even more time.

How can I fix that issue?

May be migrating this db to MS SQL will make it work faster? Could it be Firebird issue?

Comment: When it is C# and EF, then MS SQL server takes the most tooling support from MS. It may be a reason for migrating. 2.6 secs response time seems to be slow but "slow" is a relative thing that may be based on many factors. It may be your data schema, how you do your query, your indexes etc. Otherwise I wouldn't think firebird database to be that much slow (but FB is not one of databases that I use). For example checking your sample code, you are getting item.price in a loop N times when you could do that with a single call one time. This would be slow with any SQL series database.

Comment: Your code is executing a separate database query per item. This will result in bad performance no matter the database. It's hard to answer without knowing the ORM you use, the schema and ORM mappings. You should find a way to load all prices at once. You can do that either by defining a relation between the Item and Price entities and eager-loading the prices. Another way is to collect all item IDs in a list and load the prices before iterating with a `e =>itemIds.Contains( e.RAZOTAJA_KODI )` clause

Comment: Try SQL Express and see how it would perform.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Could you please write it as an answer, so as I could mark it as resolved question?